# Dynamic filtering in angularJs using multiple checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter the json data by using multiple check boxes in different categories,So far iam successful in filtering the data but what I need is to filter the categories also please go through the below fiddle  to understand this 
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mounika12/5b4hzhgg/)
 basically when I select something in pantsize category,then shirt size and shoe size filters are also filtered according to the combination,here the problem is filtering of checkboxes is happening in top to bottom direction,for example if I select something in shirt size category then only shoe size check boxes are filtered but not the pant size
Iam using the following service

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            players: $scope.players,
            usePants: $scope.usePants,
            useShirts: $scope.useShirts,
            useShoes: $scope.useShoes
        }
    }, function (value) {
        var selected;

        $scope.pantsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'pants');
        var filterAfterPants = [];        
        selected = false;
        for (var j in $scope.players) {
            var p = $scope.players[j];
            for (var i in $scope.usePants) {
                if ($scope.usePants[i]) {
                    selected = true;
                    if (i == p.pants) {
                        filterAfterPants.push(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }        
        }
        if (!selected) {
            filterAfterPants = $scope.players;
        }

        $scope.shirtsGroup = uniqueItems(filterAfterPants, 'shirt');
        var filterAfterShirts = [];        
        selected = false;
        for (var j in filterAfterPants) {
            var p = filterAfterPants[j];
            for (var i in $scope.useShirts) {
                if ($scope.useShirts[i]) {
                    selected = true;
                    if (i == p.shirt) {
                        filterAfterShirts.push(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        if (!selected) {
            filterAfterShirts = filterAfterPants;
        }

        $scope.shoesGroup = uniqueItems(filterAfterShirts, 'shoes');
        var filterAfterShoes = [];        
        selected = false;
        for (var j in filterAfterShirts) {
            var p = filterAfterShirts[j];
            for (var i in $scope.useShoes) {
                if ($scope.useShoes[i]) {
                    selected = true;
                    if (i == p.shoes) {
                        filterAfterShoes.push(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
        if (!selected) {
            filterAfterShoes = filterAfterShirts;
        }        

        $scope.filteredPlayers = filterAfterShoes;        
    }, true);
```

Comment: Did you miss to include fiddle url?

Comment: @Lini Susan I edited my question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your service and UI

Filter the checkboxes on the bases of run time filtered data on UI itself By using `ng-hide` check `<div ng-hide="(filteredPlayers | filter:pants).length==0">` line added

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
      <div class="top">
          Search: <input name="company" type="text" class="search-input" ng-model="query"/>
      </div>

<section class="left" style="border-right:1px">  
    <div class="filter">
    Pant Size
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="pants in pantsGroup">
        <div ng-hide="(filteredPlayers | filter:pants).length==0">
            <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="usePants[pants]"/>{{pants}}</b>
            <span>({{(filteredPlayers | filter:pants).length}})</span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="filter">
    Shirt Size
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="shirts in shirtsGroup">
           <div ng-hide="(filteredPlayers | filter:shirts).length==0">
            <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="useShirts[shirts]"/>{{shirts}}</b>
            <span>({{(filteredPlayers | filter:shirts).length}})</span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="filter">
    Shoe Size
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="shoes in shoesGroup">
        <div ng-hide="(filteredPlayers | filter:shoes).length==0">
            <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="useShoes[shoes]"/>{{shoes}}</b>
            <span>({{(filteredPlayers | filter:shoes).length}})</span>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>        
<section class="right" style="border-right:1px">
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="player in filteredPlayers | filter:query" >
            <p><b>Player: {{player.name}}</b></p>
            <p>Shirt Size: {{player.shirt}} Pant Size: {{player.pants}} Shoe Size: {{player.shoes}}</p>
        </li>
        </ul>    
    </div>

</section>
</div>
```

And in service Use same data set to get the different Groups

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
    //alert("test");
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][key];

        if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            result.push(value);
        }

    }
    return result;
};

function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.usePants = {};
    $scope.useShirts = {};
    $scope.useShoes = {};

    $scope.players = [
        {name: 'Bruce Wayne', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Wayne Gretzky', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Michael Jordan', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Rodman', shirt: 'XSXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
        {name: 'Jake Smitz', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Will Will', shirt: 'XXLL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Youasdf Oukls', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Sam Sneed', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Bill Waxy', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Javier Xavior', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Bill Knight', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
        {name: 'One More', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
        {name: 'Player One', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
        {name: 'Space Cadet', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Player Two', shirt: 'XXXXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'}
    ]; 

    // Watch the pants that are selected
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return {
            players: $scope.players,
            usePants: $scope.usePants,
            useShirts: $scope.useShirts,
            useShoes: $scope.useShoes
        }
    }, function (value) {
        var selected;

        $scope.pantsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'pants');
        var filterAfterPants = [];        
        selected = false;
        for (var j in $scope.players) {
            var p = $scope.players[j];
            for (var i in $scope.usePants) {
                if ($scope.usePants[i]) {
                    selected = true;
                    if (i == p.pants) {
                        filterAfterPants.push(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }        
        }
        if (!selected) {
            filterAfterPants = $scope.players;
        }

        $scope.shirtsGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'shirt');
        var filterAfterShirts = [];        
        selected = false;
        for (var j in filterAfterPants) {
            var p = filterAfterPants[j];
            for (var i in $scope.useShirts) {
                if ($scope.useShirts[i]) {
                    selected = true;
                    if (i == p.shirt) {
                        filterAfterShirts.push(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        if (!selected) {
            filterAfterShirts = filterAfterPants;
        }

        $scope.shoesGroup = uniqueItems($scope.players, 'shoes');
        var filterAfterShoes = [];        
        selected = false;
        for (var j in filterAfterShirts) {
            var p = filterAfterShirts[j];
            for (var i in $scope.useShoes) {
                if ($scope.useShoes[i]) {
                    selected = true;
                    if (i == p.shoes) {
                        filterAfterShoes.push(p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
        if (!selected) {
            filterAfterShoes = filterAfterShirts;
        }        

        $scope.filteredPlayers = filterAfterShoes;        
    }, true);


    $scope.$watch('filtered', function (newValue) {
        if (angular.isArray(newValue)) {
            console.log(newValue.length);
        }
    }, true);    
}
```

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrbL3c9w/)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for taking your time and solving this but what in the fiddle which you have done,when Iam selecting one thing in pant size remaining things are hiding but i should be able to make multiple selections using check boxes

Comment: can you make yourself more clear , coz from your question what i got that if the last block of check box been selected it is not removing other checkboxes with 0 element in it .

Comment: please elaborate with example, what you think it should work .

Comment: I should be able to make multiple selections in a category(pant size,shirt size,shoe size) and the remaining categories should give the checkboxes which are combination with the selected checkboxes

Comment: for example if I am selecting  pant size 42 in  your fiddle it is giving the shirt size and pant size of players who are having pant size as 42.Again I want to check pant size 38,then it should give shirt size and shoe size of players who are having pant size as 38,but after selecting 42 remaining sizes are hiding

Comment: That's not how filter work . If you select pant size 42 it will remove other sizes. if its not removing other sizes then it is not working properly. And by that way what about . what you want ,for that you have to write custom filters. and then it will be possible.

Comment: 1)user should be able to make multiple selections in the category he starts filtering.2)If he starts filtering from pant  size then he should be able to make multiple selections in pant size and remaining category checkboxes will filtered according to the selections in the first category.Like wise if he want to start filtering from shirt size shud be able to make multiple selections in shirt size and the remaining categories(pant,shoe)will be filtered accordingly. This is my scenario

Comment: please check my updated fiddle where I have modified the service [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mounika12/5b4hzhgg/)

Comment: then its working fine for you , or any other issue you are facing

Comment: when I am selecting pant size it is working fine it is filtering shirt and shoes,but the problem is when I select shirt only shoe will be filtered but not pants,and when shoe is selected nothing is filtered.Basically only the categories below the selected category are filtered but above that they are remaining unfiltered this is the issue

Comment: Can you help me on this?

Comment: i analyzed what you want , and i understood that , this in not possible i f you what to make it done in the way you are doing , you have to write a custom filter , and when you check a checkbox , you have to manually write the code , what all data should be visible and   what all should be filtered .check  https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters   or check https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp